# how to make the QRadioButton circle bold in pyqt?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a qradiobutton and I want to make bold like this image [image]

I tried this code but I got a square and I can't select the QradioButton:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *



class main(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 600, 500)
        self.Qradio = QRadioButton('click', self)
        self.Qradio.move(50, 50)
        self.Qradio.setStyleSheet(''' QRadioButton::indicator {border : 2px solid black;}''')
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mai = main()
    mai.show()
    app.exec()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only possibility I can think of, using stylesheets, is to set the border-radius to half the size of the radio indicator, in order to get a "circle".

You can use the default radio indicator size based on the current style:

```
        size = self.style().pixelMetric(QStyle.PM_ExclusiveIndicatorWidth)
        self.Qradio.setStyleSheet('''
            QRadioButton::indicator {{
                border: 2px solid black; 
                border-radius: {}px;
            }}
            QRadioButton::indicator:checked {{
                background: rgb(64, 64, 64);
            }}
        '''.format(size // 2))
```

Otherwise set your own, ensuring that you correctly compute the size based on the border width:

```
        size = 25
        border = 2
        self.Qradio.setStyleSheet('''
            QRadioButton::indicator {{
                border: {border}px solid black; 
                height: {size}px;
                width: {size}px;
                border-radius: {radius}px;
            }}
            QRadioButton::indicator:checked {{
                background: rgb(64, 64, 64);
            }}
        '''.format(size=size - border * 2, border=border, radius=size // 2))
```

You can even get an *inner* circle using a small trick: a radial gradient that has a "boundary" at a certain ratio from the border:

[image: checked radio]

```
        size = 20
        border = 2
        self.Qradio.setStyleSheet('''
            QRadioButton::indicator {{
                border: {border}px solid black; 
                height: {size}px;
                width: {size}px;
                border-radius: {radius}px;
            }}
            QRadioButton::indicator:checked {{
                background: qradialgradient(
                    cx:.5, cy:.5, radius: {innerRatio},
                    fx:.5, fy:.5,
                    stop:0 {checkColor}, 
                    stop:0.45 {checkColor},
                    stop:0.5 transparent,
                    stop:1 transparent
                    );
            }}
        '''.format(
            size=size - border * 2, 
            border=border, 
            radius=size // 2, 
            innerRatio=1 - (border * 2 + 1) / size, 
            checkColor='#056060'
        ))
```